# How to get string between LAST word1 entry and first word2 entry with regex using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the source text

```
some someword various-textsomeword heresomewordthis is the target stringanother text.ext another string
```

I need to get

```
this is the target string
```

after last entry of "someword" (it can be any number of entries) that can be any word

before first entry of "another" word

Using **Javascript**, so ?<= not works. Anybody can help here?

No split please)))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex, that graps everything between the 2 underlines:

```
/_.*?_(.*)?_/
```

It starts by matching the first underscore, then matching any char any number of times, then an underscore and then creates a `Group`, that graps everything between the underscores.

Your desired output will be in `Group 1`.

Comment: There is no fixed amount of underscores. So the goal is still different.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about not using regular expressions?

```js
const str = "some various-text here_someword_this is the target string_another text.ext",   
      trigger = "someword";
      
let arr = str.split("_");
let match;

// iterate through the array looking for the trigger
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++){
  if (arr[i] == trigger){
    match = arr[i+1];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(match);
```

Comment: It can be anything, not only underscores. How I must write question with source string to not get such answers?))))) Write everywhere *any character**any character*, or I will get suggestion to split by *))))) Thanks for try but no, that will not work. I need to get string after a word.

Comment: @bodich Think you need to clarify your possible inputs and the possibilities. Your example uses underscores and because you didn't say otherwise, that's how we try to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Updated post.

Comment: Hey. How I can remove that "This question already has an answer here" (which is lie). I have found coorect answer by myself but cannot even post answer here because of that flag(((

Comment: @bodich flag the question it for moderator attention